# How to add inList constraints into a variable from different class?

Tags: grails, groovy, grails-2.0, grails-domain-class

My `inList` constraints for a variable in class grew bigger. I need an alternative. One approach that I feel may work is having a list in a separate class and call that as an `inList` constraint. For instance, instead of

```
variable(nullable: true, inList:['Yes','N'])
```

can I do something like

```
variable(nullable:true, inList:domainClass.list)?
```

Any helpful hints will be appreciated.

Comment: I think you'll need to use a custom validator.

Comment: @doelleri! thanks for a quick response. Any example?

Comment: https://grails.github.io/grails2-doc/2.5.x/ref/Constraints/validator.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> variable(nullable:true, inList:domainClass.list)

That would only work if `domainClass` is the name of a class (since it begins with a lower case letter I expect it isn't) and `list` would need to be a static `List` literal.  For example:

```
class SomeClass {
    static final List SOME_VALUES = ['Yes', 'N']
}
```

Then you could do something like this:

```
variable nullable:true, inList: SomeClass.SOME_VALUES
```

I hope that helps.